# Is spadonium listed as a scanned resource?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've jumped through several systems now in the search for spadonium so I can build a science console in my base.

I've scanned each planet in each system, but none had listed spadonium. Does this mean they don't have any? I notice that carbon and titanium and such aren't listed even when they are pretty much present on all planets (I don't think it's a rarity thing, as heridium is also pretty much on all planets, and that is listed on the scanner).

So - is spadonium always listed when present? Do I just need to jump more until I find a system with what I want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spadonium is in fact listed when you scan a planet.  This is how I found mine.

When you're on a planet, Spadonium will be indicated by a purple blip with a white rectangular block in it after performing a scan.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Spadonium]

Keep on looking!

Answer (score 3):

Based on the top comment on [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/5g4r2r/any_tips_on_finding_spadonium/), it looks like if a planet has Spadonium, it will show up in the scan:

> You can scan the planets from space. There is always one violet resource so if there is no Spadonium scan another planet.

Posts in [this thread](http://steamcommunity.com/app/275850/discussions/4/154641879465533515/) also say that it will show up in scans:

> I got Spadonium - had to jump 6 systems to find a planet where it was listed as a resource on the scanner.

However, it's worth noting that Spadonium is found in cacti in desert biomes. From the [Spadonium wikia page](http://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Spadonium):

> this element can be recovered from specific cacti on desert biomes.

Comment: "it's worth noting that Spadonium is found in cacti in desert biomes" - does that mean that it can be present with being listed (like carbon)?

Comment: I think in that steam thread I linked, someone had indicated that they'd found it without it being listed. It looks like whatever is rarest is what's listed. But if you want to save time, I'd just keep scanning until you find it rather than checking even if it doesn't show up in the scan.